# Retention Plan: Apply Expiry Date Based on Term Shared Property

Tags: managed-metadata, term, retention

Is there a way to apply an **Expiry Date** via **Term > Shared Properties**?

**For example:**

- Shared Property = "Days to Expire"
- Shared Property value = 365
- **Days to Expire (365)** + **Created Date** = **Expiry Date**

The reason is that I've been asked to auto-apply specific expiry dates for our documents based on the Category. Contributors don't want to keep manually changing the Expiry Date field each time the upload or update a document.

I am using **Term Store Managed Metadata** for **Categories** such as:

- Forms: Corporate Templates --> Expire in 2 years
- Resources: Work Plans --> Expire 1 year
- Resources: Weekly Reports --> Expire 6 months

I have 5 primary categories with a dozen sub-categories in each and a few third-level or tertiary categories.

I am trying to minimize the workflows if possible. I prefer not to create and manage dates for each category via workflows.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can set this via Shared Properties, But you can use the calculated column which will set the expiry data on the basis created date.

http://blog.sharepointsite.co.uk/2011/12/add-expiry-date-to-list.html

there is OOTB SharePoint policy called Information Management Policy, if you want to take action after expiry.

[Plan for information management policy in SharePoint Server 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262490.aspx)

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ecm/archive/2011/10/12/policy-and-retention-in-sharepoint-server-2010.aspx

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mvpawardprogram/2011/10/03/applying-document-retention-in-sharepoint-2010/

Comment: Thanks but what I need is the expiry date to change based on the Term value or Category.

Comment: You can use the calucaled column, formula based on the term value

Comment: Just looked into that. The Calculated column doesn't allow the insertion of a Managed Metadata column.